# Adding a row from a List to a row in a 2nd List Powershell

Tags: powershell, arraylist, comparison, concatenation

In Powershell: I have 2 lists-FontIDList and FontDefinitionList. I want to take the first row of FontID and add the first row of FontDefinition. Repeat thru all the elements, then write to a text file. I've tried:

```
$newContent = $FontIDList2 | foreach {$_ + $FontDefList2}

Add-Content "C:\Desktop\MasterFontList-TimeStamps\TestLatestDate.txt" -value $newContent
```

As well as `$newContent = $FontIDList2 + FontDefList2`-and I'm pretty sure i need to use some kind of `foreach`, but am not sure of the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate by index instead using a `for` loop and then concatenate your strings:

```
$newContent = for ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $FontIDList.Count ; $i++) {
    $FontIDList[$i] + $FontDefList2[$i]
}
Add-Content "C:\Users\dtxxxxx\Desktop\MasterFontList-TimeStamps\TestLatestDate.txt" -value $newContent
```

Note that `Add-Content` adds to a file, not sure if that's what you actually wanted.

Comment: I did want to make a new text file(Also, would you mind removing the \dt#\ from the directory, didn't mean to post it originally). I will give this code a shot and see what it does!

Comment: Thank you-it worked perfectly, once i put in the correct names of the lists...(forgot the "2", as i used a second list to hold items from a first list). Now to run it on the master files!

Answer (score 2):

Using Linq's Zip method:

```
$selector = [func[object, object, object]] { 
    param($x1, $x2)
    $x1 + $x2 
}
[Linq.Enumerable]::Zip($FontIDList2, $FontDefList2, $selector) | Add-Content out.txt
```

Comment: Nice one! Didn't think to use Linq